# Is it a bad idea to store large vectors in the stack?

Tags: c++, vector, heap-memory, stack-memory, stack-corruption

I've been working on a bunch of image processing programs.. nothing fancy, mostly experimenting quick and dirty. The image data is stored in vectors which are declared on the stack (I try to avoid having to use pointers when I don't need to pass data around). I've noticed that some of my functions have been behaving very strangely despite countless amounts of debugging and stepping. Sometimes the debugger would give me an error that it cannot evaluate a certain variable, among other things. Things generally just do not make sense, and past experience tells me that when this happens this means that there is some kind of overflow or memory corruption going on. The first thing that came to mind was that it was probably due to me storing lots of image data into vectors.

However, I was under the impression that vectors store their actual data in the heap, and so I thought it wouldn't hurt to have a few of these large vectors on the stack. Am I wrong in thinking this? Should I be allocating my vectors and storing them in the heap rather than the stack?

Thanks,

Comment: The vector contents __are__ dynamically allocated. The vector object itself is usually tiny (12-24 bytes).

Comment: I found the problem I was facing.. I was going out of bounds in a vector that I assumed would be 3x bigger than it actually is. Thank you everyone for clarifying how vector allocation works.. It made me look in the right direction!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [...]vectors store their actual data in the heap

`vector`, like all other containers, uses an allocator object for memory management. Typically, if you don't specify anything as the template's second parameter, the default allocator -- `std::allocator` from `<memory>` -- is used. It is the allocator's responsibility to reserve memory. It is free to do so either from the free-store or on the stack.

Most implementations typically use the *pimpl* idiom and store a pointer within the `vector` object which points to the actual memory on the free-store.

> I've noticed that some of my functions have been behaving very strangely despite countless amounts of debugging and stepping

You may want to check that you are using your `vector`s properly. Look up the standard as to what gurantees you get with each member function, what conditions must be satisfied for the contained types and when your iterators get invalidated. That should be a good start.

Comment: I see.. I suppose that isn't the problem I'm facing. I'm going to go ahead and check my code properly... I'm doing certain hacks to increase performance, maybe I should look there. Are there any tools that can check for memory corruption?

Comment: Depends on your platform. Most platforms have some tool or the other. Search this site for such a tool (Valgrind for Linux, Purify for Windows etc) that best fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out valgrind

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` does not store its memory within itself. It allocates memory from the heap (or wherever your allocator gets it from). So whether the `vector` *itself* is on the stack is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I would be willing to say that 99.9% of vector implementations store all of their data in the heap.  Maybe somebody out there made a stack implementation, but you're probably not dealing with that.  If random, intermittent failures are occurring a corner case not getting checked with pointer arithmetic is more likely the case.  Either way, we can't know without you posting **code**

Comment: "Maybe somebody out there made a stack implementation, but you're probably not dealing with that." That would not be possible. `vector` doesn't allocate memory; `vector`'s *allocator* does. And `std::allocator`, the default, gets its memory from the heap.

Comment: @Nicol: But not everyone conforms to the standard.  Maybe somebody decided to do something crazy and have the default allocator trigger a template specialization that does crazy stuff like manually manipulating esp/rsp, copy stuff, and then search the stack for pointers to locations on the stack and modify those pointers.  Stranger things have happened.

Comment: @RobertMason: If your argument is "but anything could happen!" then what point is there in even conjecturing the simplest things? What if `int i` is actually `float i`, not everyone conforms!

Comment: I'd post my code, but the thing is I'm not sure what to post lol.. if that makes any sense. I'm storing 2 vector objects (images) in another class and then I allocate that class on the stack when I want to use it. The only thing in those classes that take a significant amount of space are the vectors.